# NSDateFormatter .dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" producing nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have been using this for the longest time, not sure when this stopped working. Currently using OS X 10.11.1, Xcode 7.1.1 (7B1005).
Any Suggestions?

```
import UIKit

var str = "11/31/2014"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

let dateValue = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str) as NSDate!
```

Comment: You need to study up on the calendar. November normally only has 30 days.

Answer (score 3):

Thirty days hath September, April, June, and **November**…

If you would like the date formatter to treat November 31 as December 1, you can tell it to be lenient:

```
var str = "11/31/2014"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
dateFormatter.lenient = true
let dateValue = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str) as NSDate!
```

Result:

```
"Dec 1, 2014, 12:00 AM"
```